# Function expressions are not supported in decorators or how to make an exported function

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-aot

Angular 6 project fails to compile in prod with `aot` turned on.

I know I'm supposed to turn the function expression into an exported function but with what's going on I can't get it done correctly. I looked around for people with a similar problem but wasn't helped by them. I think my instance is a bit more intense.

### The Problem File

```
export const createReducer = <T>(type: string) => () => {
    return <T>(state = createInitialState<T>(), action: any): IState<T> => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case `CLEARCACHE_${type}`: {
                return state = createInitialState();
            }
            case `CREATE_${type}`: {
                return incrementLoading(state);
            }
            ... Other cases.
        }
    }
}
```

### The Caller of the problem file

```
export const reducers = {
    company: (createReducer(getStoreKey(Company)))(),
    mortgages: (createReducer(getStoreKey(Mortgage)))(),
    ... More of the same.
}
```

I can't wrap my tiny brain around what's actually happening and how to reverse engineer it appropriately.

Let me know if you need more code or info.

Here's the full error.

```
ERROR in src\app\data\store\store.module.ts(14,27): Error during template compile of 'StoreModule'
    Function expressions are not supported in decorators in 'reducers'
        'reducers' references 'createReducer' at src\app\data\store\reducers\index.ts(13,15)
            'createReducer' contains the error at src\app\data\store\reducers\generic.reducer.ts(53,30)
    Consider changing the function expression into an exported function.
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Or just looking for information on what the above code does?

Comment: @DeborahK error is in the title.